# awk to change any values except 0,1, 2 to missing (NA)

Tags: awk, text-formatting

I have a huge file with numerical values in many columns and rows. The values for columns are all numerical and  98%  are [0 or 1 and 2]; However for some these are beyond 0,1 and 2,   for example `1.733336` or `0.4567777`. I want to replace all values that are not 0,1 and 2  to  NA.  can i do this for awk?
my input file is like this but many columns after this:

```
id  A_101   A_102   A_103
20971530    1   0   0   0
31457209    0   2   0   0
31405731    0.45663 0   0   2
40194308    0   0   0   1.7655
```

Comment: Can you provide a little example with the values contained in your file?

Comment: Can you please add your expected output? Also, does it have to be `awk` that is used?

Comment: How is the input file delimited? Is it tabs?

Comment: Are you missing a `A_104` column header?

Answer (score 3):

```bash
awk '
    BEGIN { ok[1]; ok[2]; ok["0"]; ok["NA"] }
    NR > 1 {
        for (i=2; i <= NF; i++)
            if (!($i in ok))
                sub($i "[[:blank:]]*", "NA  ")
    }
    {print}
'
```

```
id  A_101   A_102   A_103
20971530    1   0   0   0
31457209    0   2   0   0
31405731    NA  0   0   2
40194308    0   0   0   NA
```

Comment: While that would work for the current data, it'd fail if a number like `21` was part of `ok` but `1` wasn't and `21` appeared before `1` on a line as then the sub() would turn `21` into `2NA`. It just needs to test for a blank before $i as well as after and change `*` to `+` to ensure there's at least 1 blank (and add a test for $ after $i)

Comment: True. With gawk: `sub("\\<" $i "\\>[[:blank:]]*", "NA  ")`

Comment: You need to test for the end of the string too or you can have the same problem with `12` becoming `NA2`. Hmm, I'm not sure that using `\\<` and `\\>` will help since `.`, which can appear mid-number, isn't a word-constituent character so something like `1.3` or `3.1` might end up being `NA.3` or `3.NA`. I'd have to really think about and test that one (which I'm not really going to)!

Comment: Yeah `sub` isn't the best way to do this, but I was trying to preserve the original whitespace.

Comment: Admirable goal but what you have wouldn't do that anyway as it'll replace every match for `[[:blank:]]*` with a single blank char.

Comment: yes, some of the ids in first column has been chnaged

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '
    NR>1 {
        for ( i=2; i<=NF; i++ ) {
            if ( $i !~ /^[012]$/ ) {
                $i = "NA"
            }
        }
    }
    { print }
' file | column -t
id        A_101  A_102  A_103
20971530  1      0      0      0
31457209  0      2      0      0
31405731  NA     0      0      2
40194308  0      0      0      NA
```